# Display Categories and subcategories using CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have two table in my database, One is Categories and the other is Sub_Categories, I want to display them like this:

```
Categorie 1 
sub categoie 1 
sub categoie 2 
sub categoie 3 
sub categoie 4
Categorie 2 
sub categoie 1 
sub categoie 2 
sub categoie 3 
sub categoie 4
```

But i don't know how to do this.
In my Database table i have this fields :
Categories: ID, Name, Icon.
Sub_Categories: ID, Categ_id, Name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work;

```
public function get_categories()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('Categories');
    $return = array();

    foreach ($query->result() as $category)
    {
        $return[$category->id] = $category;
        $return[$category->id]->subs = $this->get_sub_categories($category->id); // Get the categories sub categories
    }

    return $return;
}


public function get_sub_categories($category_id)
{
    $this->db->where('Category', $category_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('Sub_Categories');
    return $query->result();
}
```

All this does is get's all the categories, but then gets all the subcategories for each of the categories. Calling the get_categories() function should return an object in the format you want.

I hope this helps.

**Edit**

You would call the get_categories function from your controller and pass it to the view;

```
$data['categories'] = $this->your_model->get_categories();
$this->load->view('view_file', $data);
```

Then within your view you would display them like this;

```
<ul>
<?php 
    foreach ($categories as $category)
        {
?>
    <li><?php echo $category->name; ?>
<?php
    if(!empty($category->subs)) { 
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($category->subs as $sub)  {
            echo '<li>' . $sub->name . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
?>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: how can i display in the view

Comment: Thank's man , i have an other question . i have in my index page left side where i will display the categories and sub categories and the right side i will display something else from database . is it good to send all that data from controller in one array or not . and thank's in advace

Comment: If I just want to show subcategories of clicked category then ?

Answer (score 0):

Database
[image for database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s5Td.jpg)
Try this
in Model

```
public function getCategories()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('select * from categories where cat_parent=0');
    return $query->result_array();
}
public function getCategoriesSub($parent)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("select * from categories where cat_parent='$parent'");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

in Controller

```
public function categories()
{
    $data['mcats'] = $this->admin_model->getCategories();
    foreach($data['mcats'] as $key =>$val){
        $subcats = $this->admin_model->getCategoriesSub($val['cid']);
        if($subcats){
            $data['scats'][$val['cid']] = $subcats;
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('admin/header');
    $this->load->view('admin/category_list', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/footer');

}
```

In view

```
<ul>
<?php 
foreach ($mcats as $key =>$val)
    {
?>
<li><?php echo $val['cat_name']; ?>
<ul>
<?php
    foreach ($scats[$val['cid']] as $sub)  {
        echo '<li>' . $sub['cat_name'] . '</li>';
    }
?>
</ul>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

its already working code - i think it is usefull